# initial values from state of material-ui dropdown in redux-form

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, react-redux, redux-form

I have a material-ui dropdown menu inside a redux-form, and I want to initialize its value.
I am getting both the value that I want [`exercise.exercise_type_id` and `exercise.exercise_type_name`] and the list of available options [`types`, array of objects with `id` and `name` properties, among others] by dispatching two actions:

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.props.actions.exercise.fetchInfo(this.props.params.exerciseId);
    this.props.actions.exercise.fetchAllTypes();
};
```

Ideally I would like to have **somewhere** something like:

```
_.map(this.props.types, (type) =>{
            if (type.id == this.props.exercise.exercise_type_id){
                this.setState({
                    dropDownValue: type.name
                });
            }
        });
```

but only for the initial state, since we want to handle changes with `handleDropDownChange`.

[Of course I would appreciate something like

```
state = {
    dropDownValue: {this.props.exercise.exercise_type_name}
};
```

but I know this is an anti-pattern. But anyway it doesn't work, props are still empty.]

My dropdown is like this:

```
<DropDownMenu {...exercise_type_name} //does nothing
        value={dropDownValue}
        onChange={onDropDownChange}>
    {_.map(types, (type) => {
        return <MenuItem key={type.id} value={type.name} primaryText={type.name}/>;
    })}
```

More code:

```
//...

state = {
        dropDownValue: ''
    };

//...

handleDropDownChange = (event, index, value) => {
        this.setState({
            dropDownValue: value
        });
    };

//...

  function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        exercise: getExerciseInfo(state),
        initialValues: getExerciseInfo(state),
        request: getExRequest(state),
        types: getExTypes(state)
    };
}

//....

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'EditExerciseForm',
    fields: ['exercise_type_name', 'max_errors_percentage', 'min_speed']
}, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExerciseEdit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, turned out simpler than what I expected.

This fixed my issue:

In the `DropDownMenu` component its value should be like:

```
value={dropDownValue || exercise_type_name.value}
```